# Can some series be seasonally unadjusted while others are adjusted in a VAR model?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, seasonality, macroeconomics

I am modeling a SVAR to explain how oil price shocks have an impact on stock price, after downloading time series from the FRED database I noticed that Consumer Price Index is seasonally adj. unlike the other time series.

Can I implement CPI or do I need to remove seasonality from the other time series?

Comment: What is sVar? Structural vector autoregression? That would be SVAR. (While value at risk is VaR, for example.)

Comment: Yes Structural vector autoregression